# How to call Image Title on Attachment Page (Wordpress)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

On the Attachment Page, there is only 1 image and what is the function to call the title for this image?
I want to echo the image title at one more place on the same page, how can I do that?

Comment: it's seems you theme have single-attachment.php template you need to override that file through your child them and add the title based on your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`get_the_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/).

```
$image_title = get_the_title($image_id);
```